# Matching two unordered streams by property, RxJava, RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, rx-java

Having two streams like the following

```
Stream 1: A -- B -- C -- D
Stream 2: 3 -- 1 -- 2 -- 4
```

I'd like to output

```
Output: A1 -- B2 -- C3 -- D4
```

OR

```
Output: 3C -- 2B -- 1A -- 4D
```

Where each letter is matched against it's position on the alphabet.
I've tried using the operators `.zip` and `.combineLatest` but didn't get the result I'm looking for.

This is in fact a simplification of my problem, in reality. A, B and C are objects which have a properties like 1,2 or 3. So I can do something like `A.position() = 1`

Is there an operator that specifically solves my problem, or will I have to use a hash map and match these objects myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is .zip and .cimbineLatest operators?

Comment: they are reactive operators http://reactivex.io/

Comment: Thanks for the simple abstraction of your problem in the question, it makes a nice change! Interesting problem by the way particularly to handle infinite streams and handle backpressure nicely (not your use case perhaps but still interesting).

Comment: In your second output option `1A` should be before `2B`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Observable.toSortedList` like below:

```
Observable<Data> s1 = Observable.from(new Data[]{new Data(3), new Data(1), new Data(2), new Data(4)});
Observable<String> s2 = Observable.from(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D"});

Observable.zip(
        s1.toSortedList(this::compare).flatMap(Observable::from),
        s2,
        (d, s) -> s + d.number
).subscribe(s -> {
    //Output: A1 -- B2 -- C3 -- D4
});
```

`compare` method:

```
private Integer compare(Data a, Data b) {
    return a.number.equals(b.number) ? 0 : (a.number < b.number ? -1 : 1);
}
```

`Data` class:

```
class Data {
    private final Integer number;

    Data(Integer number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I might have chosen a bad example in my answer, but "toSortedList" wouldn't work for my porpuse The stream s1 contains objects with ids, not numbers. I will re write my answer to make it more generic.

Answer (score 0):

i would try something like .flatMap() on one stream with .groupBy(key) on the other stream, which will produce Observable<GroupedObservable<YourType>>

or otherwise use .toMap() or .toMultimap() on the other stream, which will produce Observable<Map<K,Collection<T>>>

not sure whether you expect a particular order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unit-tested [match](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras#transformersmatchwith) operator from rxjava-extras 0.8.0.3 (or later if available). The artifact is published on Maven Central.

Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.davidmoten</groupId>
  <artifactId>rxjava-extras</artifactId>
  <version>0.8.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Example:

```
Observable<Integer> a = Observable.just(1, 2, 4, 3);
Observable<Integer> b = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4);
Obs.match(a, b,
     x -> x, // key to match on for a
     x -> x, // key to match on for b
     (x, y) -> x // combiner
    )
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
3
```

Comment: Please note that I'm just completing a unit tested operator `match` in rxjava-extras. The above algorithm doesn't handle repeats properly. I'll let you know when ready, will be released in the next couple of days.

Comment: replaced my answer with the newly written operator. Let me know if any problems (preferrably as an issue on rxjava-extras on github).